# After the home page was redirected by a hack, it is no longer indexed. How long until it comes back?

Tags: google, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, pagerank, hacking

My site was hacked, and the index page was 302 redirected. It took me a few months to get all this sorted. In the meantime, the home page lost its PageRank and was no longer included in the index.

I have since got my homepage back in, but the positions and traffic are not yet where they were before. How long might it take for the link juice to proliferate back through the site?

Comment: It will vary by site. Could be quick. Could be slow. No one knows.

Comment: but it will return?

Comment: If you cleaned everything up, probably. Can't say for sure because if sites that linked to you removed their links due to the hack that will have a negative effect on your rankings. (Meaning you won't rank as well as before).

Comment: It has been my experience that you will begin to recover once Google *fully* realizes your site has changed. This can take weeks 2-3 perhaps. However, as long as your site has been incorrect, it will likely take that long to get back to where you were. Not always, but generally true. Your performance will recover pleasantly soon enough, it just will not be full speed and may be frustrating. I urge you to be patient. Google is slow. And when you begin regaining fully, you will be pleased that it was a fairly reasonable recovery. Trust me. You will be okay.

Answer (score 3):

Did you follow the guidelines for removing the malicious codes and following the hacked site guidelines? The last step is submitting a request for review, which can be done here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2600725?hl=en

To expedite the process, I would submit a fresh sitemap to Google, but I would give it 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

I have had several cases where rankings were lost due to technical problems:

- extended downtime
- canonical tags that point to the wrong thing
- noindex tags accidentally applied to all pages

In my experience your rankings do eventually return.  It can, however, take awhile.  As a general rule, I would expect rankings to return in about three times the amount of time for which the problem existed.  So if the redirect hack existed on your site for four months, it may take a year for your rankings to fully recover.